# Alternative to Director for infotainment cross-platform apps

Tags: android, ios, user-interface

I'm looking for a visual IDE similar to [Adobe Director](http://www.adobe.com/products/director.html) for creating interactive apps in the style of ['The Elements'](http://apps.theodoregray.com/the-elements/) – think interactive books with support for 3D content, video, language translation, etc.

The reason for not using Director is that I'm unsure if it's still being actively developed, and I'd also like to opportunity to drop into platform native code.

Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe LiveCode ? Programming language and general environnement are very similar...